# Product Name not found in Magento Category Page

Tags: php, magento

I have this following code for the category page display in list.phtml placed at the location app\design\frontend\ultimo\default\template\catalog\product

The line productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?> does not output the name of the product. Please help.

The entire code has been pasted below for reference.

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
?>

<?php if ($_collectionSize && $tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_above_collection')): ?>
    <div class="block_category_above_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!$_collectionSize): ?>
    <?php if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_above_empty_collection')): ?>
        <div class="block_category_above_empty_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="note-msg empty-catalog"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>

<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
    $labelsHelper = $this->helper('ultimo/labels');
    $templateHelper = $this->helper('ultimo/template');

    //Default image size
    $imgWidth = 295;
    $imgHeight = 295;

    //Aspect ratio settings
    if ($theme->getCfg('category/aspect_ratio'))
        $imgHeight = 0; //Height will be computed automatically (based on width) to keep the aspect ratio
?>

<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>

    <?php //List mode specific settings

        $listClasses = $theme->getCfg('category_list/hover_effect') ? ' hover-effect' : '';

        //Check if "Add to" links are displayed as simple icons
        $isListAddtoSimple = $theme->getCfg('category_list/addtolinks_simple');
    ?>

    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list<?php if($listClasses) echo $listClasses; ?>" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">

            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image grid12-4 persistent-grid2-1">

                <img src="<?php echo $theme->getImgUrl($this, $_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, 'small_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />

                <?php //Product labels
                echo $labelsHelper->getLabels($_product); ?>

            </a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop grid12-5 persistent-grid2-1">
                <div class="product-shop-inner">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-column grid12-3 persistent-grid2-1">
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php
                if ($isListAddtoSimple)
                    echo $templateHelper->getCategoryAddtoLinks($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product));
                else
                    echo $templateHelper->getCategoryAddtoLinks($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-textlink');
                ?>
            </div>

        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>



    <?php else: ?>
    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php //Grid mode specific settings

        //Get grid configuration array
        $gc = $theme->getCfgGroup('category_grid');

        //General grid classes
        $gridClasses = $gc['hover_effect'] ? ' hover-effect' : '';
        if ($gc['equal_height'])
            $gridClasses .= ' equal-height'; 
    ?>

    <ul class="products-grid category-products-grid itemgrid itemgrid-<?php echo $gc['column_count']; ?>cols<?php if($gridClasses) echo $gridClasses; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true); ?>" class="product-image">

                    <img src="<?php echo $theme->getImgUrl($this, $_product, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, 'small_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true); ?>" />

                    <?php //Product labels
                        echo $labelsHelper->getLabels($_product); ?>

                </a>

                <?php //Add-to links
                    if ($gc['display_addtolinks'] != 0 && $gc['addtolinks_simple'])
                    {
                        if ($gc['display_addtolinks'] == 1) //Display on hover
                            echo $templateHelper->getCategoryAddtoLinks($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-onimage display-onhover');
                        else //Always display
                            echo $templateHelper->getCategoryAddtoLinks($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-onimage');
                    }
                ?>

                <h2 class="product-name">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">

                <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>

                </a>
                </h2>

                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php if ($gc['display_rating'] == 1): //Display on hover ?>
                        <div class="display-onhover"><?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?></div>
                    <?php elseif ($gc['display_rating'] == 2): //Always display ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

                <div class="actions clearer">
                    <?php if ($gc['display_addtocart'] != 0): ?>
                        <?php $btnClass = ($gc['display_addtocart'] == 1) ? ' display-onhover' : ''; ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart<?php echo $btnClass; ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock<?php echo $btnClass; ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php //Add-to links
                        if ($gc['display_addtolinks'] != 0 && !$gc['addtolinks_simple'])
                        {
                            if ($gc['display_addtolinks'] == 1) //Display on hover
                                echo $templateHelper->getCategoryAddtoLinks($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-textlink display-onhover');
                            else //Always display
                                echo $templateHelper->getCategoryAddtoLinks($_product, $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product), 'addto-textlink');
                        }
                    ?>
                </div> <!-- end: actions -->
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($_collectionSize && $tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_below_collection')): ?>
    <div class="block_category_below_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you using list.phtml for custom block file or for default.

Comment: For a default... Yet the names do not show up. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.